# Stop Docker container from exiting after running command

Tags: puppet, docker

I want to use the [following docker file](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-in-docker/blob/master/puppet-agent-ubuntu/Dockerfile) as a base for learning puppet. It was written in a way that it runs some puppet commands and then immediately exits.

I'm trying to understand where the container tells itself to shutdown so I can modify it to stay running. The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER Gareth Rushgrove "gareth@puppet.com"

ENV PUPPET_AGENT_VERSION="1.8.3" UBUNTU_CODENAME="xenial"

LABEL org.label-schema.vendor="Puppet" \
      org.label-schema.url="https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-in-docker" \
      org.label-schema.name="Puppet Agent (Ubuntu)" \
      org.label-schema.license="Apache-2.0" \
      org.label-schema.version=$PUPPET_AGENT_VERSION \
      org.label-schema.vcs-url="https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-in-docker" \
      org.label-schema.vcs-ref="a2b1fbbc73177ddc3def23d167f9beb9c3ef9f6c" \
      org.label-schema.build-date="2017-02-21T17:25:14Z" \
      org.label-schema.schema-version="1.0" \
      com.puppet.dockerfile="/Dockerfile"

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y wget ca-certificates lsb-release && \
    wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-pc1-"$UBUNTU_CODENAME".deb && \
    dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-pc1-"$UBUNTU_CODENAME".deb && \
    rm puppetlabs-release-pc1-"$UBUNTU_CODENAME".deb && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y puppet-agent="$PUPPET_AGENT_VERSION"-1"$UBUNTU_CODENAME" && \
    apt-get remove --purge -y wget && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV PATH=/opt/puppetlabs/server/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:$PATH

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet"]
CMD ["agent", "--verbose", "--onetime", "--no-daemonize", "--summarize" ]

COPY Dockerfile /
```

How can I modify this so that it doesn't shut down right away?

Comment: Whatever command you run upon container start needs to not exit. So, just create a shell wrapper script that starts your puppet process and then never exits.

Comment: @EEAA would that be from outside the container or inside using the RUN keyword?

Comment: It must be inside.

Comment: @EEAA so I just use RUN with a command that shouldn't finish? I tried adding "watch ." which keeps running normally in bash, but the container still exited.

Comment: What @EEAA mean't is to write a script like `agent --verbose --onetime --no-daemonize --summarize && sleep infinity` and put it on the `CMD`/`ENTRYPOINT` step of your Dockerfile. But AFAIK the puppet-agent is meant to exit after it executes it's task. Maybe you could explain a little better your point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that removing `"--onetime"` from the following lines:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet"]
CMD ["agent", "--verbose", "--onetime", "--no-daemonize", "--summarize" ]
```

From [what I'm reading](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/man/agent.html) the `--onetime` option changes the exit code returned which was triggering an exit.